# How to set different label for different view for a single model usign CreateView

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I have a model that i am using in two view for two purpose.
how can i set different lebel for a field.

```
class ChapterCreate(CreateView):
model = models.Chapter
fields = [
    'title',
    'content',
    'order',
]
```

I have tried with

```
class Chapter(models.Model):
    order = models.IntegerField(verbose_name= _('Chapter number'))
```

but this changes to my model itself.
But i want to use same model in different view with different label field

Answer (score 0):

```
class ChapterCreate(CreateView):
    model = models.Chapter
    fields = [
        'title',
        'content',
        'order',
    ]
    labels = {
        'order' : 'Chapter number'
    }
```